# Golang for loop with multiple brackets

Tags: loops, go, struct, composite-literals

I've stumbled upon this repository,

https://github.com/prometheus-community/jiralert/blob/a0f0e80e575e71cbf7db565d3296a3a984282dff/pkg/config/config_test.go#L148

The for loop has multiple brackets:

```
for _, test := range []struct {
        missingField string
        errorMessage string
    }{
        {"Name", "missing name for receiver"},
    (...)
    } {

        fields := removeFromStrSlice(mandatory, test.missingField)

    (...)
        }
        configErrorTestRunner(t, config, test.errorMessage)
    }
```

I haven't been able to find anything about this in the go documentation, what is this construct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first bracket pair is part of the [struct type](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Struct_types) definition which has the syntax:

```
struct{
    field1 type1
    field2 type2
    ...
}
```

The second pair is part of the [composite literal](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Composite_literals) value, creating a value for the [slice](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Slice_types) of this struct. It has the syntax of:

```
[]elementType{value1, value2, ...}
```

The inner, embedded brackets are part of the composite literals creating the struct values of the slice. The type is omitted (it's known from the slice type), so each `{field1Value, fieldValue2...}` is a struct value.

The third pair defines the block of the `for` statement. The `for` statement iterates over the elements of the slice defined by the mentioned composite literal.

Answer (score 1):

To clean up the code for better readability and understanding. Whatever you gave was equivalent to:

```
type TestStruct struct {
  missingField string
  errorMessage string
}

testCase := TestStruct {
  {
    missingField: "Name",
    errorMessage: "missing name for receiver",
  }
  (...)
}


for _, test := range(testCase) {

  fields := removeFromStrSlice(mandatory, test.missingField)
}
```

`configErrorTestRunner(t, config, test.errorMessage)` is probably from a parent test func